# Power platform Center of excellence (CoE) - remove solution layers

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am in the process of upgrading the Centre of Excellence (CoE) core component solution. As we know, before upgrading, we need to remove the solution layers, if any, from the solutions, as per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/coe/after-setup). All flows start with "Admin | Sync Template v.", We need to remove the solution layers.

Then, how about other flows that don't start with "**Admin | Sync Template v**" and have the solution layer active? Should we remove these as well?

For example, other flows such as "**Admin | Add Maker to Group**", "**Admin | Capacity Alerts**", "**Admin | Compliance Detail Request v3**," etc.